# Return call from ggplot object

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been using `ggplot2` for a while now, and I can't find a way to get formula from `ggplot` object. Though I can get basic info with `summary(<ggplot_object>)`, in order to get complete formula, usually I was combing up and down through `.Rhistory` file. And this becomes frustrating when you experiment with new graphs, especially when code gets a bit lengthy... so searching through history file isn't quite convenient way of doing this... Is there a more efficient way of doing this? Just an illustration:

```
p <- qplot(data = mtcars, x = factor(cyl), geom = "bar", fill = factor(cyl)) + 
     scale_fill_manual(name = "Cylinders", value = c("firebrick3", "gold2", "chartreuse3")) + 
     stat_bin(aes(label = ..count..), vjust = -0.2, geom = "text", position = "identity") + 
     xlab("# of cylinders") + ylab("Frequency") + 
     opts(title = "Barplot: # of cylinders")
```

I can get some basic info with `summary`:

```
> summary(p)
data: mpg, cyl, disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, vs, am, gear, carb [32x11]
mapping:  fill = factor(cyl), x = factor(cyl)
scales:   fill 
faceting: facet_grid(. ~ ., FALSE)
-----------------------------------
geom_bar:  
stat_bin:  
position_stack: (width = NULL, height = NULL)

mapping: label = ..count.. 
geom_text: vjust = -0.2 
stat_bin: width = 0.9, drop = TRUE, right = TRUE 
position_identity: (width = NULL, height = NULL)
```

But I want to get code I typed in to get the graph. I reckon that I'm missing something essential here... it's seems impossible that there's no way to get call from `ggplot` object!

Comment: I took a look at `p` with both `str()` and `dput`, and I couldn't find the call.  Might not be possible.

Comment: How about using a script file? If you are using R-GUI, you then easily use it. e.g., File->New opens a new blank script file. Without saving it, you can eval the script file (in mac, command-E or command-enter).

Comment: kohske, I'm using GNU/Linux distribution, Emacs+ESS, and I'm afraid that there's no GUI whatsoever... at least not a "regular GUI"... But the thing that's quite unclear to me is: "What did you mean with `script file?`" I mentioned a way to get call from `.Rhistory` file, but that's just not what I'm looking for... I'll try my luck on `ggplot2` group... this definitely seems like a convenient feature...

Comment: Matt... yup, no luck... bunch of objects, but `call` just ain't there!

Comment: I mean that if you use a script file instead of console, you can easily get the previous call in the script file without retrieving from .Rhistory. Of course you can use a script file in the ESS environment. This is not a solution for your question, but a kind of workaround. I agree with you, it is convenient if ggplot2 object has a call.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding... late night log-ins. I usually get `ggplot` calls from `.Rhistory` to a separate script file, for batch processing. In fact, I do that all the time, but I wanted to do this the other way, from `ggplot` object directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not currently possible to go from a ggplot2 object to the code that (might have) created it.

Comment: I was waiting to hear this from you! =) Do you think this is a good idea? I'd certainly like to see this feature implemented in fresh release(es)...

Comment: It's on my to do list, but not very high up, because unfortunately it requires quite a lot of rewriting :/

Answer (score 3):

You can store any R code as an expression with 'expression()' and then evaluate it with 'eval()'.
e.g.

```
p <- expression(qplot(data = mtcars, x = factor(cyl), geom = "bar", fill = factor(cyl)) + 
     scale_fill_manual(name = "Cylinders", value = c("firebrick3", "gold2", "chartreuse3")) + 
     stat_bin(aes(label = ..count..), vjust = -0.2, geom = "text", position = "identity") + 
     xlab("# of cylinders") + ylab("Frequency") + 
     opts(title = "Barplot: # of cylinders"))
```

then

`eval(p)`

will produce the plot but the original code is still stored in the variable 'p' as an expression.

so

`p`

produces

```
expression(qplot(data = mtcars, x = factor(cyl), geom = "bar", 
    fill = factor(cyl)) + scale_fill_manual(name = "Cylinders", 
    value = c("firebrick3", "gold2", "chartreuse3")) + stat_bin(aes(label = ..count..), 
    vjust = -0.2, geom = "text", position = "identity") + xlab("# of cylinders") + 
    ylab("Frequency") + opts(title = "Barplot: # of cylinders"))
```

which is what we started with.

'eval()' can also evaluate a character string as an expression if parsed as text with parse(), e.g.

`eval(parse(text='f(arg=value)')`

Comment: Of course I can, string (character) should also suffice. Something like this: `s <- "rnorm(10)"; eval(parse(text = s))`. But obviously, there's no way of doing this directly, since `ggplot` objects do not have `call` element in the list.

Comment: Sure. But if ggplot isn't saving you input in the object it returns, then something like this is going to be your only option.

Comment: @aL3xa. Added the other way to use eval() as you suggest.